# Errors result when attempting to copy an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to copy an array, however I keep getting problems. I've tried it in 2 different ways, but none work.

1st try:

```
function classA(id, arrayFrom, arrayTo)
{
  this.id = id;
  this.from = arrayFrom.slice(0);
  this.to = arrayTo.slice(0);
};
```

Output:

> Uncaught TypeError: arrayFrom.slice is not a function

2nd try:

```
function classA(id, arrayFrom, arrayTo)
{
  this.id = id;
  this.from = {arrayFrom[0], arrayFrom[1], arrayFrom[2]};
  this.to = {arrayTo[0], arrayTo[1], arrayTo[2]};
};
```

Output:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Unuseful details. Share the code with the calls to that function.

Comment: The methods are fine, whatever you are passing to them, they aren't arrays

Comment: `arrayFrom` is *not* an array.  Please show us what it actually is.

Comment: By the way none of those function will copy an array ^^

Comment: The first code example works perfectly fine if you pass it appropriate arguments: https://jsfiddle.net/5c44wzgy/.  I'm going to guess that you're passing plain objects, not arrays.

Comment: @SteevePitis  slice(0), will copy an array.  What it won't do is a deep-copy, but for primitive types like integer etc it would be fine.

Comment: The problem is likely what you are passing to the `classA` constructor (not passing Arrays).  My guess is that you are passing plain objects, not arrays.  We cannot help you further without seeing exactly what you are passing.

Comment: And it's fixed :) You guys were right, I was passing some kind of struct instead of an array. Couldn't have figured it out without your help ^^ How do I close the question now?

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise your instance with real arrays. Then it works without error.

```js
function classA(id, arrayFrom, arrayTo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.from = arrayFrom.slice(0);
    this.to = arrayTo.slice(0);
}

var aFrom = [1, 2, 3],
    aTo = [42, 43, 44],
    a = new classA(0, aFrom, aTo);

aFrom[0] = 100;
console.log(a); // the instance does not change to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `ClassA` with "array like" iterable arguments such as a node list for instance then you may do like `this.from = Array.from(arrayFrom)`.

```js
function ClassA(id, arrayFrom, arrayTo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.from = Array.from(arrayFrom);
    this.to = Array.from(arrayTo);
}

var obj = new ClassA(1,{0:"a",1:"b",length:2},{length:0});
console.log(obj);
```

`Array.from()` works even the supplied object has no iterator but just a `length` property.

Answer (score -1):

```
function classA(id, arrayFrom, arrayTo){
  this.id = id;
  this.from = arrayFrom.slice(0, arrayFrom.length);
  this.to = arrayTo.slice(0, arrayTo.length);
}
```

Let's try with this :)
But your functions didn't copy an array... i just write right your code ;)

Comment: "*arrayFrom.slice is not a function*"

Comment: It seems he isnt passing an array :\